# Running SQL Master Script With String Replacement

Tags: sql, oracle

I recently took over the duty at my office of building and running scripts to deploy updates to an Oracle database.

My predecessor in this task (who no longer works here) used a syntax that looks like this to call each script from a master script:

```
@"<My_Project_Name Codebase Location>\{path within our TFS repository}";
--the <> was in the original, the {} was added by me
```

I was able to search to learn that the @"..." will indeed call the referenced script.

However, I have been unable to find anything about the <...> syntax. It appears to be a variable substitution, but the value isn't defined anywhere that I can see.

I am also not clear whether this was intended to be run in Visual Studio, Toad, SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, or something else.

Comment: Is there a $symbol within <> ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is just a *placeholder*, i.e. a *note* which says that you should put location (folder, directory) which contains .SQL file you're about to run instead of the whole <...> *thing*. Basically, it could have been something like

```
@c:\my_sql_files\news.sql
```

so you'd overwrite that with actual directory & file name each time you run it.

For example:

```
c:\Temp>dir c:\users\*.sql
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 7635-F892

 Directory of c:\users

14.03.2018.  20:03                25 news.sql       --> this is the file I want to run
               1 File(s)             25 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  346.474.045.440 bytes free
```

As it is located in c:\users, I should use that path in order to run it. Without the path, that won't work (unless there's the NEWS.SQL in current directory):

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sri O×u 14 20:03:47 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


Session altered.

SQL> @c:\users\news.sql   --> c:\users is path to my NEWS.SQL file

SYSDATE
----------
14.03.2018

SQL>
```